# visual studio 2013 is not responding

Tags: visual-studio-2013

i have recently installed visual studio 2013 ultimate on my 64 bit windows 8.1 x64 based system 
whenever i open visual studio 2013 it shows an error box saying "Microsoft visual studio 2013 is not responding."

```
     <p>how can i fix this problem</p>
```

Comment: Are you using the pirated copy of VS2013 Ultimate or a legitimate licensed copy? If you have a licensed copy you have access to support from Microsoft to help solve problems. If you installed the pirated copy it could be the trojans and malware are interfering with normal operations.

Comment: No i have just download it from microsoft.com

Comment: Did you install VS Update 3? And had it worked for you and then stopped working?

Comment: no i have not installed update 3

Answer (score 0):

It may have 2 reasons :

1. your Windows is not compatible with that version of VS2013
2. your CPU or RAM is lesser than VS needs